# Is it possible to turn the clear property of select to "false" for bar graphs?

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I have a concatenated graph with two sets of data being displayed. By selecting bars on the left graph you can change the data shown on the right graph. I would like to prevent the user from being able to clear the selection and am trying to set {"select": {"clear": false}} to achieve this, however it is not working. Whenever I click outside of the graph or if I double click on the bars, the selection clears.

I have tried this using an example bar graph in the vega-lite examples page and that is also not working. So I am just wondering if this is not possible for certain types of graphs or if there is a specific way of doing it. I have attached the code for the bar graph that does not work with the clear: false property and for a heatmap that does work.

**Not working bar graph:**

Vega-lite link to graph: https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABEyTrDsU5kMB3OjEMwaZGMOc7ZZQ3IdtSZpLLKhhBwgnBQ7p7eUMJQANaUhgAUAJKyEDg06nBBTACehgAqSExhSAwA5BCGNLKYcOpIEbrBmHlhlACUiipImCiooMRIggxqaADaoAMg+j1MaABMABwAvgrTaCAAQvNoYmLrm+gAwnuoACwAzEcgMwAi5wCcAIy3MwCi58tvG3dbADFzmIbn8ZgBxc4vJ7vLYACW+AHZYegUsDFqsALrrEA4UxIBAQSagWQEuBbRzOVxYHohMIRNCgNo4cnoHBsWqYHoxOCmLYAMxGIRAq1upIQrJAdPCXKU0oZbI5dRFmKUyHUcUZIGZkpM6h6-JogkEWwAxBcTojlvplrTMOo2HFdYImpqlFAGOoZPrFZyGiKlHBZFA2MpamQtQAPLWG0LKLYoJQ6rZsdRh0kmnF5GM0ONbBZJvIsrYARwYAR0-R0pADIENxoA8nioHRs4MQCHAnRdFq8Y0EFt5bKQMNRqzfiORmM0AAGSigqX2x1wADqNGU9C1nbDOjkxNx+IH6EpLicNKUo+nqAxfz7BIpZ+pw8v46xF6nrJnovdckNEfb0AjKyoAmIEAAKSDKOmZBpLI-qoHOGKikAA

Code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A bar chart with highlighting on hover and selecting on click. (Inspired by Tableau's interaction style.)",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 28}, {"a": "B", "b": 55}, {"a": "C", "b": 43},
      {"a": "D", "b": 91}, {"a": "E", "b": 81}, {"a": "F", "b": 53},
      {"a": "G", "b": 19}, {"a": "H", "b": 87}, {"a": "I", "b": 52}
    ]
  },
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "highlight",
      "select": {"type": "point", "clear": "false"}
    },
    {"name": "select", "select": "point"}
  ],
  "mark": {
    "type": "bar",
    "fill": "#4C78A8",
    "stroke": "black",
    "cursor": "pointer"
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "ordinal"},
    "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"},
    "fillOpacity": {
      "condition": {"param": "select", "value": 1},
      "value": 0.3
    },
    "strokeWidth": {
      "condition": [
        {
          "param": "highlight",
          "value": 2
        },
        {
          "param": "highlight",
          "value": 1
        }
      ],
      "value": 0
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "scale": {
      "bandPaddingInner": 0.2
    }
  }
}
```

**Working heatmap graph:**

Vega-lite link:https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoJFEwMdaEAEFFIHACc4ymmedXbSqGwazMaAEYAZgBfBRMzC0EPO0dnV0x3dAAhO29ff1QABjCI80t0T3snFzdlKwBhNJ8-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

Code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"actual": "A", "predicted": "A", "count": 13},
      {"actual": "A", "predicted": "B", "count": 0},
      {"actual": "A", "predicted": "C", "count": 0},
      {"actual": "B", "predicted": "A", "count": 0},
      {"actual": "B", "predicted": "B", "count": 10},
      {"actual": "B", "predicted": "C", "count": 6},
      {"actual": "C", "predicted": "A", "count": 0},
      {"actual": "C", "predicted": "B", "count": 0},
      {"actual": "C", "predicted": "C", "count": 9}
    ]
  },
  "params": [
    {"name": "highlight", "select": {"type": "point", "clear": false}}
  ],
  "mark": {"type": "rect", "strokeWidth": 2},
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"field": "actual", "type": "nominal"},
    "x": {"field": "predicted", "type": "nominal"},
    "fill": {"field": "count", "type": "quantitative"},
    "stroke": {
      "condition": {"param": "highlight", "empty": false, "value": "black"},
      "value": null
    },
    "opacity": {"condition": {"param": "highlight", "value": 1}, "value": 0.5},
    "order": {"condition": {"param": "highlight", "value": 1}, "value": 0}
  },
  "config": {
    "scale": {"bandPaddingInner": 0, "bandPaddingOuter": 0},
    "view": {"step": 40},
    "range": {"ramp": {"scheme": "yellowgreenblue"}},
    "axis": {"domain": false}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between heatmap and bar chart seems a bit different from your understanding:

- heatmap rects fill up all area on the grid
- bar chart leaves some area on the grid outside the bars

As a result, upon clicks **outside the grid**, both won't clear the selection as you desire. However, clicks on the **empty area inside the grid** of bar chart emit an event with nothing selected, thus clearing the original selection.

I'm not sure if you know there is a [`toggle` property](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/selection.html#toggle) for `select`. When it is true, any newly clicked point is inserted to the selection, thus clicking on the empty area adds nothing and preserves your previous selection. BUT, a side effect is that multi selection will be allowed...

```
  "params": [
    {"name": "highlight", "select": {"type": "point", "toggle": "true"}},
    {"name": "select", "select": {"type": "point", "toggle": "true"}}
  ],
```

Last but not least, according to the Doc, [`clear` property](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/selection.html#clear) specifies an event to clear the selection. Yet, I'm not sure what happens when it is set as false.

> clear property identifies which events must fire to empty a selection of all selected value